# регулярка для сниппета в vs code, как выполнить цепочку операций?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, visual-studio-code

"${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/.+\\(.+)\\index.ts/${1}/g}"

вот это регулярное выражение мне выдает

из `src\pages\task-details-page\index.ts` => `task-details-page`

но как дальше из `task-details-page` получить `taskDetailsPage` не особо понятно

синтексиса каторый бы продолжил операцию(цепочку) над `${1/.../g}` не могу найти, уже тучу вариантов перепробовал

в js например => `.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`